# Collecting NIC teaming information on Server 2008 R2/PowerShell 2

Tags: networking, powershell, bonding

Is there a way to do this via WMI?  I've collected info but am not sure what to look at as far as identifying interfaces as set up with teaming.  Nearly  all the servers that have teamed interfaces are on Server 2008 R2/PowerShell 2, so Get-NetlbfoTeam and similar cmdlets are not available.

Comment: WIndows 2008 does'n't have its own teaming option. So it differs per NIC manufacturer (Broadcom,Intel,HP)

Comment: I know 2008 R2 doesn't natively support teaming, though teaming can be set up.  To paraphrase my question: Is the information related to teaming stored anywhere accessible on Server 2008 R2?